# Asking professor to provide feedback on academic articles?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I sent an email to a potential supervisor whether I fit for him, he said yes, then I replied whether he ll be able to provide feedback on a paper I am writing on a topic of his interest, he didn't reply, was that a good move from my side?

Comment: A paper like one you would write as an assignment for a class? Or a paper you intend to publish in a scientific journal?

Comment: a paper I intend to both publish in a journal and submit with the application as a writing sample. Remember, I am still a prospective student in the supervisor's eye!

Comment: "Remember, I am still a prospective student in the supervisor's eye!" Right, so I'm trying to understand why you are asking them to edit the writing you are working on and do work on your behalf. Don't you want to present polished material to someone who is evaluating your suitability?

Comment: I usually do not reply to such a request.  I do not commit to a student until they are enrolled.  No free labor!

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus I really like that.

Comment: @BryanKrause Well, it's goes like this: I am a prospective student, I am interested in applying to your program, meanwhile, I am writing a paper to submit, if it is possible to do a favor for your potential student so he presents a good application. Prof. Santa argued against this, and I like that.

Comment: BUT, what I am asking is whether I left a bad impression by saying that?

Comment: On top of the previous, very relevant comments, I would add that just asking for feedback is a lazy way of initiating an interaction. A more engaging way would be one or two questions tailored to their expertise and interests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing a scientific article for publication is time consuming. By asking a prospective supervisor to review your scientific article, you were asking him to take hours out of his or her busy day. The journal you are submitting to will have reviewers who are volunteers and will review your article.

Comment: Few people respond well to blind requests unless there is a previous relationship between the people.

Comment: @Buffy Right, that s true, but I what I am asking is whether I left a bad impression by saying that?